# The revision number given by 'svn checkout' is different from svn log

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Here is the information I got using 'svn info $url'

`Path: ChIPseqBioinforCore
URL: https://xx.xx.xx.edu/xx/xx/xx
Repository Root: https://xx.xx.xx.xx/xx
Repository UUID: 3d1f76f3-e2fd-4989-95aa-7b479c330932
Revision: 197
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: xxx
Last Changed Rev: 184
Last Changed Date: 2016-12-21 14:29:39 -0500 (Wed, 21 Dec 2016)*`

If I use 'svn checkout $url', the last line is:
`Checked out revision 197.`

If I use 'svn log -l 1 $url', the log information is:

`r184 | xxx | 2016-12-21 14:29:39 -0500 (Wed, 21 Dec 2016) | 1 line`

`add --no_align, --min_base_qual, --min_read_length`

If I use 'svn log -l 1 ', the log information is the same as `svn log -l 1 $url`.

How does this happen? I don't understand why my last revision is 184 based on the log. But 'checkout' and 'info' give 197.

Thanks.